# Tensorflow: Output where max is 1 and rest is 0

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am working on a special case of a convolutional network for solving puzzles, which partly will be reused to classify images later. Currently I am working on setting up the final layer of the puzzle part.

Each puzzle consists of 9 pieces, and y_hat is a 81(9x9) long nparray containing the original position of each piece.

For the network I use a Tensorflow functional model, where the final layer is 9 small sub models softmaxing to indicate where the piece should go. I was wondering if there is any way to make the last layer of the submodels only output 1 for the  highest value after softmax and 0 for the rest? I have been searching for days now. This still have to be a part of the neural network, so it can be used when training.

What I mean is:

```
[0.01,0.41,0.02,0.32,0.01,0.43] => [0,0,0,0,0,1]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to classify things, then use `from_logit=True` in `tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy`<sup>[1]</sup> or `tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy`<sup>[2]</sup>, and output `tf.keras.layers.Dense` layer. softmax calculation will be done in these loss functions.

By putting one_hot layer and softmax layer into one layer, computational efficiency gets better. You don't need to make your own one_hot layer for the output of your network. Just set

If you want to your own one_hot vector converter layer, I have an idea to keep a graph differential. Use very big parameter known as thermodynamic beta in softmax.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

class OneHot(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, infi=1e9):
        super(OneHot, self).__init__()
        self.infi = infi

    def call(self, x):
        return tf.nn.softmax(self.infi * x) # x has shape [B, 9]

    def get_config(self):
        return {'infi': self.infi}
```

See how it works below.

```py
>>> a = tf.constant([[1.,2.], [3., 4.]], dtype=tf.float32)
>>> tf.nn.softmax(a)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0.26894143, 0.7310586 ],
       [0.26894143, 0.7310586 ]], dtype=float32)>
>>> tf.nn.softmax(1e9 * a)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0., 1.],
       [0., 1.]], dtype=float32)>
```

I am not sure how this output layer makes learning better.

== My first answer below. Not recommended.

You can use `tf.one_hot`<sup>[3]</sup> to make it.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([0.01,0.41,0.02,0.32,0.01,0.43], dtype=tf.float32)
i = tf.argmax(x)
y = tf.one_hot(i, 6)
# <tf.Tensor: shape=(6,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.], dtype=float32)>
```

If you want to make a keras layer, make custom layer<sup>[4]</sup>.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

class OneHot(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(OneHot, self).__init__()

    def call(self, x):
        i = tf.argmax(x, axis=1) # x has shape [B, 9]
        return tf.one_hot(i, 9)
```

[1] https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CategoricalCrossentropy
[2] https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/SparseCategoricalCrossentropy
[3] https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/one_hot
[4] https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models

Comment: About making it differentiable, there are some options, you can also do e.g. `i = tf.argmax(x); max_v = x[i]; y = tf.concat([tf.zeros(i, dtype=x.dtype), [max_v / max_v], tf.zeros(tf.size(x, out_type=i.dtype) - i - 1, dtype=x.dtype)], axis=0)`, and it is technically differentiable, but the gradient is useless... Since OP says this is for the last layer, I'd suggest just changing the loss function to use the values before this final activation function (the "logits").

Answer (score -1):

`index = tf.argmax(one_hot_vector, axis=0)`

Searching with "one hot decode" may help you.

Comment: This is not an answer, but a comment.